# While Loop with Table Update

Tags: sql-server, string, loops, while-loop

I have a problem with a `While` Loop in SQL Server.

What I want to do is to split something like:

```
'@Name=John;@Surname=Kowalsky;@DATA=data;'
```

Into table with 2 columns where one will be `'@Name'` and second one `'John'`

After every split I wrote an update to delete the split string and start from new one but that doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (x varchar(max), y varchar(max))
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1, '@Name=John;@Surname=Kowalsky;@DATA=data;')
CREATE TABLE test (x varchar(max), y varchar(max))

DECLARE @y varchar(max) = (SELECT y FROM test2)
WHILE (SELECT LEN(y) FROM test2) > 0

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test (x,y)
    VALUES ((SUBSTRING(@y, CHARINDEX('@', @y)+1, CHARINDEX('=',@y) -CHARINDEX('@',@y)-1)),
            (SUBSTRING(@y, CHARINDEX('=', @y)+1, CHARINDEX(';',@y) -CHARINDEX('=',@y)-1)))

    UPDATE test2
    SET  y = REPLACE(y, SUBSTRING(y, 1, CHARINDEX(';', y)), '')
    FROM test2
END
```

In return I'm getting table test with 3 same rows: NAME / JOHN

So this loop does this job ALMOST correctly... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mistake you made was not updating the variable `@y` for each iteration of the loop. The following solves that, and for clarity tidies up the variable usage, i.e. uses a variable instead of a temp table, and only uses a single variable rather than two for the data being processed:

```
-- Input data
DECLARE @Test2 VARCHAR(MAX) = '@Name=John;@Surname=Kowalsky;@DATA=data;';

-- Output table
DECLARE @Test1 TABLE (x VARCHAR(MAX), y VARCHAR(MAX))

-- While we still have data to process
WHILE LEN(@Test2) > 0 BEGIN
    -- Extract one pair from the input string and put into the output table
    INSERT INTO @Test1 (x,y)
    VALUES ((SUBSTRING(@Test2, CHARINDEX('@', @Test2)+1, CHARINDEX('=',@Test2) -CHARINDEX('@',@Test2)-1)),
            (SUBSTRING(@Test2, CHARINDEX('=', @Test2)+1, CHARINDEX(';',@Test2) -CHARINDEX('=',@Test2)-1)))

    -- Update the variable @Test2 each iteration, removing the processed data
    set @Test2 = REPLACE(@Test2, SUBSTRING(@Test2, 1, CHARINDEX(';', @Test2)), '');
END

SELECT * FROM @Test1
```

Returns:

```
x       | y
--------| --------
Name    | John
Surname | Kowalsky
DATA    | data
```

Comment: Are you sure about `SELECT LEN(y) FROM test2`?

Comment: Oh man `(SELECT LEN(y) FROM test2) > 0 ` will throw an error if `test2` contains more than 1 row

Comment: Readers won't look to all his question, and test2 here is a table. For me it's better to answer it according the info provided, or use it as a variable and fix the code instead.